# Alternatives to the word think over

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Context : I want me and my partner to think over some problem example a math problem think over 
solution to it. Come up with solution

Some lines that come to my mind are -

1. Let's ponder over it
2. Lets think over it.

I am not sure if these are correct 
How is the word brainstorming different from pondering over / think over

Comment: Consider it, give it some thought, reflect on it, weigh it up, head-scratch

Comment: 'Pondering over' means something or some issues knocking inside you, Maybe It's quite unintentionally.  But 'Thinking over ' means you are consciously putting you Energy on some thing over and over to find solutions.

Comment: _Brainstorming_ is a technique in which a group of people suggest as many ideas as they can for solving a problem - rather different from two people thinking carefully about it.

Comment: You can use "ruminate".

Answer (score 2):

Few alternatives I found on [dictionary.com](https://dictionary.com), are:

> [cogitate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cogitate#)(verb-used without object):
>
> - to think hard; ponder; meditate.
>   Example - to ***cogitate*** about a problem.

> [figure out](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/figure?s=t)(informal verb phrase):
>
> - to understand; solve. Example - We couldn't ***figure out*** where all the money had gone.
> - to calculate; compute.

> [deliberate](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/deliberate#)(verb):
>
> - (used with object)to weigh in mind; to consider. Example - to ***deliberate*** a question.
> - (used without object)to think carefully or attentively; reflect. Example - She ***deliberated*** for a long time before giving her discussion.